# Moderate Effect Interpretation

Tags: logistic-regression

Hello I'm studying the moderate effect of one continuous variable, family income, on the relationship between gender (dummy variable) and whether attending school (dummy variable).

[image]

For the first model, I only put the dummy variable, gender (female), and the coefficient for gender is 0.128.

For the second model, I put the interaction term, gender by family income, and the continuous variable, family income. The new coefficient for gender is 0.086, and the coefficient for the interaction term is 0.128. I am wondering how family income affects the relationship between gender and whether attending school, as females compared with males. Which coefficient should I look at? Should I only look at the coefficient of the interaction term to say that family income strengthens the relationship between gender and whether attending school? Or can I also mention the new coefficient of gender, to say that after considering the moderator, family income, the likelihood for females to attend school is lower? Appreciate your help.